# How would I write the equiv. of this query in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to query a table in rails using this query (found [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html)):

```
    Select ID, Postcode, Lat, Lon, 
       acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos($lat)*cos(radians(Lat))*cos(radians(Lon)-$lon))*$R As D
From MyTable 
Where acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos($lat)*cos(radians(Lat))*cos(radians(Lon)-$lon))*$R < $rad
```

(finds all points located within a certain radius of a given point)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use [GeoKit-Rails](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/) (or [GeoKit-Rails3](https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3)). Then your queries will look like this:

```
Store.find(:all, :origin => @somewhere, :within=>10)
```

or the Rails3 version:

```
Location.within(5, :origin => @somewhere)
```

where `@somewhere` is a point (`[37.792,-122.393]`), zip, address, etc.

Comment: It says within is an undefined method.

Comment: Did you do 'bundle install'? Did you add `acts_as_mappable` to your model?